# Удаление файла на сервере

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет !

Есть некий код, который генерирует файл. По нажатию на **`Button`**, этот файл скачивается. Хочу сделать его **удаление** с сервера.

***Написал вот такой код:***

```
public ActionResult DeleteAllFiles(string path)
        {
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/"));
            var files = directory.GetFiles().ToList();

            foreach (var deletedFile in files)
            {
                if (deletedFile.Extension == ".jpg")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (deletedFile.Exists)
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(deletedFile.FullName);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return View("Error" + e);
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Не совсем понимаю, в каком месте мне нужно использовать его. То есть, что бы не было такой ошибки:

> файл занят другим процессом или действие не может быть выполнено, так
>   как этот файл открыт в Название_программы

**UPD:**

какие есть способы получение пути к файлам на сервере ? То есть как я могу получить путь к сгенерированному файлу. Спасибо !

Comment: Вам надо удалять один файл или все ".jpg" файлы?

Comment: @Igor желательно один, который сгенерировался. Я пробовал удалить абсолютно все файлы.

Comment: "как я могу получить путь" ?? - `Server.MapPath`

Comment: @Igor то есть при помощи 'Server,MapPath' я получаю доступ ко всем файлам на сервере ? То есть, мой алгоритм будет работать для всех файлов .jpg и очистит сервер от них ?

Comment: `Server.MapPath` преобразует виртуальный путь к папке или файлу в физический - и все. Сможете ли Вы что-то удалить зависит от того, есть ли у акаунта, под которым запущен Application Pool для Вашего приложения, достаточно прав.

Comment: Видимо когда вы генерируете файл jpg, вы его не освобождаете, он скорей всего занят IIS процессом.